# reload on same tr after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr id="main_account">
        <td width="50%">
            <h3 style="margin-left:10px">Details</h3> 
            <table width="270">
                <tr>
                    <td>First name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="id_first_name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="id_last_name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- other html -->
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="authorised_reporter">
        <td  width="100%" colspan="2">                            
            <form method="post" action="." id="reporter-form">                                    
                <table  width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px;">First name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="id_first_name" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="id_last_name" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Daytime phone:</td>
                        <td><input id="id_phone_daytime" type="text" class="trim-space" name="phone_daytime" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

onpage load id #main_account is shown and id #authorised_reporter is hidden.If #authorised_reporter is clicked  #authorised_reporter is in display block and #main_account is in display none state.In #authorised_reporter tab i am updating the user data using ajax,after sucess call i am reloading the page.Since onload i am showing the #main_acount by default after reload it takes me to #main_account but what i required is after sucess ajax call on pagereload the page should show #authorised_reporter tab and not #main_account tab.

I tried the below but not working,takes me to #main_account

```
//other code not shown
success: function() {  
    location.reload();
    $('#authorised_reporter').css("display", "block");
    $('#main_account').css("display", "none");
    $("#sucess").show();
    $("#sucess").text("Changes has been updated."); 
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a demo?

Comment: The main reason you use AJAX is so you **don't** have to submit a form/reload the page. Return the new content for the affected/updated sections in response to the AJAX call, then update the required sections of the page using jQuery/JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below:

**Example: 1**

```
$("#main_account").hide();
```

if the answer is not related to you please disregard it.

---

**Example:2**

To have graceful degredation as well, you could stick with the hiding done via jQuery, just give the edit `<tr>` rows a class, e.g. `<tr class="edit">` then hide all of those at once with jQuery outside the table, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("tr #main_account").hide();
});
</script>
```

This approach, instead of hiding them off the bat with CSS is more friendly to those with JS disabled, if you might have an audience of users like that, go with this `.hide()` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your changes may not apply since,

```
location.reload();
```

It will reload the content and later part of success function will not effect. If you can be more specific and supply more html, will be able give you an answer. You can use **.done()** in jQuery also.